# Configure JSX User Snippets in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, code-snippets

Is there a way to create my own JSX user snippets in VS Code? I tried configuring the `javascriptreact.json` file, but inside the return statement of a React component it does not work. It does work using the `javascript.json` file, but I don't want to see those snippets while using plain Javascript. I also don't want to use global or project snippets. Here is an example of a JSX-Snippet:

```
"Create contact list": {
    "prefix": "cl",
    "body": [
        "<div>",
        "\t<ListContacts",
        "\t\tcontacts={this.state.contacts}",
        "\t\tonDeleteContact={this.removeContact}",
        "\t/>",
        "</div>"
    ],
    "description": "Creates JSX code for contact component",
}
```

Using the "Inspect Editor Tokens ans Scopes" from the command palette, the language seems to be `jsx-tags`, but I can't find a json file for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your snippet - located in `javascriptreact.json` - works fine for me in a `jsx` file I suspect that you are trying to insert it within backticks.

If that is the case you will need to modify the `editor.quickSuggestions` setting to include `strings` otherwise vscode will not surface your snippet inside the backticks. So try:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": true
},
```

Comment: I created a new react app (using npm create-react-app) and this time my snippets worked inside javascriptreact.json. I cannot reconstruct why it isn't working in my previous project. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's one of the my snippets

```
{
  "snView": {
    "prefix": "snView",
    "body": [
      "import React from 'react';",
      "import PropTypes from 'prop-types';",
      "",
      "import useStyles from './styles';",
      "",
      "const $1 = ({ $2 }) => {",
      "  const classes = useStyles()",
      "",
      "  return (",
      "    <div className={classes.container}>",
      "      <p>test</p>",
      "    </div>",
      "  )",
      "}",
      "",
      "$1.propTypes = {",
      "};",
      "",
      "export default $1;",
      ""
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  }
}
```