# Is there a shortcut to writing html tags in React? VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm tired of typing `<` then `tagname` then `>` for my HTML tags to autofill in React.

I know in angular I can just write the tag name then hit tab and it will auto-complete.

Is there a shortcut for this in react? Or an extension I can install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure JSX User Snippets in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979365/configure-jsx-user-snippets-in-vs-code)

Comment: See [Snippets in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by typing `div` (for example) and hitting enter. This is a feature built in by default in VSCode, but it'll only work for relevant file types. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) is more info about it and a list of the relevant file types